# Executing parallel tests in a Selenium keyword driven framework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-grid

In a data-driven framework, we use Selenium along with TestNG to run multiple tests in parallel. **How can the same be implemented in a keyword-driven framework?**

In data-driven approach we can define every test case as a separate method and therefore we are able to command TestNG via annotations which methods to run and how many to run in parallel.

In keyword-driven approach, every test case is a separate Excel Sheet and multiple excel sheets in the same workbook make a test suite. How can these excel sheets/test cases be annotated/referred so as to run in parallel similar to the execution structure and process in data-driven framework?

One lame solution I thought of was a hybrid approach wherein creating methods which would call the excel sheet.

For eg.:

```
@Test
public void TestCase_001() {
       // Read the keyword driven test case
       // XLS_WorkbookName - The Excel Workbook or Test Suite containing multiple Test Cases
       // XLS_SheetName - The Excel Sheet containing set of rows each of which contains ID of element, Operation to be performed and data to be used
       ReadAndExecuteTestCase(XLS_WorkbookName_XYZ, XLS_SheetName_ABC);
}

@Test
public void TestCase_002() {
       // Read the keyword driven test case
       // XLS_WorkbookName - The Excel Workbook or Test Suite containing multiple Test Cases
       // XLS_SheetName - The Excel Sheet containing set of rows each of which contains ID of element, Operation to be performed and data to be used
       ReadAndExecuteTestCase(XLS_WorkbookName_ABC, XLS_SheetName_XYZ);
}
```

I'm not sure if they above example is the appropriate way to go about it. Requesting suggestions to the same. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be :

1. Have a master sheet of cases to execute, which acts as your suite.
2. Have your dataprovider read this master sheet and have a single @Test method which takes in the arguments of the testcase data.
   This testcase basically reads the steps and executes - something like your ReadAnExecureTestCase method.
3. Make this dataprovider parallel and control using dataprovider thread count.

Comment: Sounds like a solution. Let me give it a try. Thanks. Will get back once done.

Comment: Hi Zeeshan,Have you done this solution,me also facing same issue